# Filtering NSArray with Predicate leaves extra result?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sorting, core-data, nspredicate

I have an NSArray containing NSDictionary objects.

I need to filter the objects based on a selection of values, so i have created an array of the values i want to filter by and using a predicatewithformat and feeding it the array of objects.

This is kind of working, but weirdly in situations where i know i should be getting an empty array returned i am getting a single object, that shouldn't be there.

I have logged out the value of the array of filter values, and i can clearly see that it contains a key which corresponds to the id_str of the object, so it shouldn't be returned.

Below is the code i am using, any pointers of where i am going wrong would be very vert helpful!

```
                 //Create new fetch request
             NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

             //Set new predicate to only fetch tweets that have been favourited
             NSPredicate *filterFavourite = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"favouriteTweet == 'YES'"];

             //Setup the Request
             [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tweet" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext]];

             //Assign the predicate to the fetch request
             [request setPredicate:filterFavourite];
             NSError *error = nil;

             //Create an array from the returned objects
             NSArray *favouriteTweets = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
             NSAssert2(favouriteTweets != nil && error == nil, @"Error fetching events: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);

             //Create a new array containing just the tweet ID's we are looking for
             NSArray *favouriteTweetsID = [favouriteTweets valueForKey:@"tweetID"];

             NSLog(@"%@", favouriteTweetsID);

             //Create a new predicate which will take our array of tweet ID's
             NSPredicate *filterFavouritsearchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(id_str != %@)" argumentArray:favouriteTweetsID];

             //Filter our array of tweet dictionary objects using the array of tweet id's we created
             NSArray *filteredTweets = [self.timelineStatuses filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterFavouritsearchPredicate];

             //Send those tweets out to be processed and added to core data
            [self processNewTweets:filteredTweets];

             NSLog(@"Update Favoutited Tweets: %@", filteredTweets);
```

Comment: Can you please also post the `NSLog` output? And how it deviates from what you expect to see?

Comment: Are you sure there are no leading / trailing spaces in your strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably not doing what you intent:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(id_str != %@)" argumentArray:favouriteTweetsID];
```

It is equivalent to

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(id_str != %@)", id1, id2, ... idN];
```

where id1, id2, ..., idN are the elements of `favouriteTweetsID`.
The format string has only one format specifier,
 so that everything but
the first element is ignored and you just have

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(id_str != %@)", id1];
```

If you want to filter all objects where `id_str` is not equal to any of the array elements,
use

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT id_str IN %@", favouriteTweetsID];
```

Comment: You my friend are an absolute legend, and what you have put makes complete sense now that you have written it, wood for trees moment i think! Thanks!